# Shell script: open multiple terminals and run commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a very simple shell script that opens and runs five instances of my program. With batch, I would do something like this:

```
@echo off
python webstore.py 55530
python webstore.py 55531
python webstore.py 55532
exit
```

That would open three terminals and run the commands on each of them with different command line parameter. How would I create the same with a shell script that runs on every single unix-based platform? I've seen some commands for opening terminals, but they are platform specific (gnome-termial, xterm and so on).

Comment: I don't know perfect solutions to this. You can get the default shell via the `$SHELL` environment variable but opening a new terminal is not the same as opening a new terminal *window* - opening a new shell using `exec "$SHELL"` shouldn't open a new window either. You could do `sudo apt-get install xdotool` and `xdotool key ctrl+shift+n` - that might be a somewhat "cross distro"-solution since most window managers support ctrl+shift+n for opening new windows

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641683/how-can-i-send-commands-to-specific-terminal-windows) out (using xdotool to open three terminal windows and send commands to them)

Answer (score 3):

> How would I create the same with a shell script that runs on every single unix-based platform?

What you're asking for is a bit unreasonable. Think about it that way: on Windows, you're always inside its [Desktop Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager), period, and the only choice you have is between Powershell and `cmd.exe`. But on Linux, it's a little more complicated:

1. Like you said, you can have either `rxvt` or `xterm` installed.
2. This is not the only issue though - you can use any window manager. While this does not matter much here,
3. You can be either using Xorg, or Wayland. Continuing on,
4. You can not use any graphical environment at all, e.g. run everything in Linux console! Which, unless you use fancy programs such as `fbterm` or `tmux`, is pretty much incapable of multitasking, yet alone spawning new windows.
5. That being said, you may even not use this computer physically at all, because you're connecting to it from SSH. No remote windows here either (unless you use stuff as X11 forwarding).
6. Finally, you can use `zsh`, `bash`, `sh`, `fish` etc. that all come with their own idiosyncrasies.

IMO your best bet is to test in your script which programs are installed, or script around a terminal multiplexer such as `tmux` and require it to be installed on the target machine. `tmux` in action:

[image: tmux in action]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://tmux.github.io/ss-tmux2.png))</sub>

(This will work in either SSH, Linux console, or any other scenario above.)

If you, however, do not care about the output of the commands you're about to run, you can just detach them from your current terminal session like this:

```
command1 &>/dev/null &
command2 &>/dev/null &
command3 &>/dev/null &
```

Be mindful that this:

1. Will run the commands in parallel.
2. Won't show you any output. If you remove `&>/dev/null`, the output from each command will interwine with each other, which is probably not what you want.
3. Closing the terminal usually kills its children processes, which, in this case, will kill your `command` instances that work in the background.

Issues mentioned above can be worked around, but I believe it is a little out of scope for this answer.

Personally I'd go either for `tmux` or for detaching solution depending on whether I need to see the console output.

Comment: Point 2 in the last list can be addressed by using `nohup`, couldn't it?

Comment: Yep, but I believe it goes a little out of scope of the question - I just wanted to briefly present OP possible options without going too much into detail.